# Quizzing users on key points of the EULA?

Tags: usability, installation

Is it too annoying to have a summarized "de-legalesed" version of the EULA for users to read, and then have a simple quiz on the EULA that must be passed before installation continues?

For example, it could be something like this:

- How many devices are you allowed to distribute this software to? ***_*__**
- Are you allowed to distribute this software freely? (y/n)

etc.

This seems to be a good idea to me, as people often don't read EULAs at all and then are surprised when they discover some ridiculous term in the EULA that allows them to get ripped off. I also want to give the user peace of mind that I'm not stuffing in secret unexpected terms in the EULA.

Comment: Good EULA summarized form http://tosdr.org/

Comment: Why don't you summarize the EULA in a few points with next buttons to pass between them, then provide a link for anyone that wants the long version?

Comment: You may think you are helping the user understand the terms. The user will think you are interrogating their morality.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I think DannyVarod's and Brendon's comments combined form a complete answer to your question.

Comment: How to make EULAs more annoying? = add a quiz.

Comment: Also, it seems like your true objective here is to make sure users understand the "Ridiculous terms in the EULA that allows them to get ripped off". I'd suggest that that should be the summary of the EULA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## UX Ludicrousies

EULA and T&C are nothing but a barrier for users. Although it may be a legal requirement, the fact you even need to agree to these is a pain for users, let alone read these.

EULA and T&C are some of the best examples of counter-usability: Nobody wants or has the time to read them; they are long, boring, often phrased in a language that is hard to understand, and likely to be presented at the worse time - when you are buzzing to try out your new product.

UX designers often search for the least harmful way to present these gremlins to users, within the legal requirements.

## Annoying Users Could Cost you Business, or even Your Job

So I can hardly think of a better way to annoy users than a quiz on EULA. In fact, if during an installation I would come across such quiz, I would call your helpline and ask the adviser to go with me clause-by-clause through the agreement.

I would even go as far as to say that your idea could well result in you losing your job. Please be aware of the possible dire consequences your proposal may have.

Just imagine my medical insurer would give me a quiz on their T&C. While not understanding these could cost me a fortune, the moment I would be asked to take  such a quiz would also be the moment I'll leave my insurer.

How about we stop people from leaving computer-game retailers before we make sure they understand copyright laws, infringement and what they can or cannot do with their copy?

I might come across as bold here, but for a reason - I really think this idea can lead to some serious consequences.

## The Right Way

If anything is super important within the EULA, use appropriate design and IA to present key points to the user, and a 'more' link to the full agreement. For instance, on the installation wizard you may wish to include:

- **3** is the maximum amount of device you can install this software on.
- **Distribution** is great for fresh milk, but alas - it is illegal for you to distribute this software.